# Alternative to side slider animated by position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a div that slides out when you click on it.

Here are some images of what I am trying to achieve:

This is the Div, collapsed by default
[image: default modal]

This is the Div after it is slid out (highlighted)

[image: div slid out]

This is what happens after screen size is changed. The clickable div is present behind content **Which I wish to avoid**.
[image: div after resizing window]

My Div's CSS:

```
.sliderDiv {
    z-index: -10;
    position: relative;
    left:  200px;
    width: 240px;   
}
```

I use this command to slide it out on click:

```
slideItOut:function(){
            var divsize=$(".sliderDiv").offset().left-150;
            if(divsize>100){
                $(".sliderDiv").animate({
                    "left":"-=194px"
                },"slow");
            }
            else{
                $(".sliderDiv").animate({
                "left":"+=194px"
                },"slow");
            }
        }
```

The problem is when you resize, it is not responsive at all and the div actually hides behind other content. Maybe this method is not supposed to be responsive.

**Is there a way to make the same "slider" responsive or atleast hold its position while the screen size is changed?**
I want to know of any way in which I could resize my window or screen and the div remains in same area as the 1st two images.

Also, this is being implemented in a modal. So its not exactly in a fixed area of the screen.

Comment: Increase the `z-index` of the slider div

Comment: that would result in my slider being over my important data

Comment: updated question with images

Answer (score 0):

It won't solve without your full source code, I think. You should give its source code or put somewhere. Then, I try to fix. Or, I can offer optimum way